# Moment.js / Date Range picker hours conversion can't pick more than 23 hours ahead

Tags: momentjs, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

When I change from AM/PM to 24 clock the hour picker only allows to go 23 hrs ahead. Is this a common error with Date range picker or moment.js conversion problem?

I will upload my picture in case moment.js takes time from my servers? And can't go beyond 23 hrs...

[image]

Also please see codepen with my code.

```
"setStartDate": [moment().startOf('day')],
"setEndDate": [moment()]
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WMOmOO

Comment: when I change to AM/PM display it works flawlessly. Also updated codepen and Added :SS to format - now it shows 23:02:99 in input field, so clearly some conversion problem?

Comment: Pay attention to `format` option, `MM` stands for month while lowercase `mm` stands for minutes, you got a typo in the linked codepen.

Comment: @VincenzoC thank you very much! it was a typo (shame on me... ) .Thanks again!

Comment: Why     "startDate": [moment().startOf('day')],
    "endDate": [moment()] will result in invalid date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to the `format` option, you have to use valid moment tokens, `MM` stands for month while lowercase `mm` stands for minutes, `SS` stands for fractional seconds, use lowercase `ss` for secods, see moment [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) for further reference.

Moreover `startDate` and `endDate` [options](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options) accept *Date object, moment object or string*, you are passing an array, that is why you are getting Invalid Date.

Here a live snippet:

```js
$('#demo').daterangepicker({
    "timePicker": true,
    "timePicker24Hour": true,
    "autoApply": true,
    "locale": {
        "format": "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss",
        "separator": " - ",
        "applyLabel": "Apply",
        "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
        "fromLabel": "From",
        "toLabel": "To",
        "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
        "weekLabel": "W",
        "daysOfWeek": [
            "Su",
            "Mo",
            "Tu",
            "We",
            "Th",
            "Fr",
            "Sa"
        ],
        "monthNames": [
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
        ],
        "firstDay": 1
    },
    "startDate": moment().startOf('day'),
    "endDate": moment()
}, function(start, end, label) {
  console.log("New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')");
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" id="demo" style="width: 300px;"></input>
```